# How to make type=“number” to positive numbers only using ember js

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js

It was only preventing negative numbers from being entered from up/down arrows, whereas user can type negative number from keyboard.

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label>Quantity</label><br>
           {{input type="number" value=quantity min="0" class="form-control- 
           invoice"}}
</div>
```

Comment: One power of emberjs is it's great addon community. There are several [validation addons](https://emberobserver.com/categories/validations) for client side validation.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example for *data down, actions up* (DDAU) principle. The data should flow down to your component (or element) but only by updated by your application if it matches certain criteria. Sadly the [`{{input}}` helper](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/input?anchor=input) does not support DDAU principle. But you could easily accomplish your goal without using it:

```
<input type="number" value={{quantity}} onchange={{action "updateQuantity" value="target.value"}} min="0" >
```

We are using a standard `<input>` element and bind it's `value` property to `quantity`. We bind a custom action to the `change` event. In that action we could check if the updated value meets our criteria and if so update `quantity`. The action may look like the following:

```
actions: {
  updateQuantity(val) {
    val = parseInt(val);
    if (val >= 0) {
      this.set('quantity', val);
    } else {
      window.alert('number must not be negative');
      this.notifyPropertyChange('quantity');
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that we have to call `notifyPropertyChange()` if the new value does not meet our criteria. This will trigger an update of UI to reset the value of the `<input>` element.

I've written an Ember Twiddle demonstrating the approach: https://ember-twiddle.com/bcf03934667364252e52b21930d664fd?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C